# Why is my Flask request object always empty?

Tags: post, flask, python-requests

I'm creating a stupid endpoint which just logs the posted data.

```
@app.route("/add_foo", methods=['POST'])
def add_foo():
    logger.debug(request.data)
    print(request.args.get('foo'))
    return "Success"
```

I then attempt to post data to this endpoint:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/add_foo", data={'foo': 'foobar'})
```

And I see the following output:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2016-07-28 08:59:22,432 - __main__ - DEBUG - b''
None
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2016 08:59:22] "POST /add_foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Interestingly, when I post the data through curl, I see the same thing. Here's my curl command:

```
curl -XPOST -d "{'foo': 'foobar'}" "http://localhost:8080/add_foo"
```

What is wrong with the data being posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.args` accesses *URL query parameters*, parameters in the URL, after a `?`. You are POSTing values into the body of the request, so use `request.form` instead.

From the [*Request Object* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#the-request-object) in the Flask Quickstart:

> To access form data (data transmitted in a POST or PUT request) you can use the `form` attribute.
>
> *[...]*
>
> To access parameters submitted in the URL (`?key=value`) you can use the `args` attribute[.]

You could also use the [`request.values` object](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.values), which combines the data from the `request.args` and `request.form` objects; `args` is searched before `form`.

Comment: Interesting. `request.data` only captures these query params, as well?

Comment: @erip: `request.data` is the unparsed raw body. `request.form` is that data parsed out into a dictionary, provided you have a request with the right content-type  (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`).

Comment: I might expect the raw body to be non-empty, especially if unparsed. I can confirm that using `request.form` worked, but I still find `request.data` to be a bit nebulous.

Comment: @erip: from the [Werkzeug `BaseRequest` class documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data): *Note that if the form data was already parsed this method will not return anything as form data parsing does not cache the data like this method does.*

Comment: @erip: for efficiency sake form data parsing doesn't keep the request body around because it could potentially be very large indeed (think file uploads).

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. :) Excellent explanation. Will accept soon.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I am relatively new to working with requests and responses and it wouldn't have occurred to me to look for `form`. Now getting the data I expected (an hour ago).